# "&amp;" in XML validation using Xerces

Tags: xml, html-entities, xerces

I am using Xerces for validation of XML, but for an tag having enum as `{Profit &amp; Loss}`

When I am giving value as `Profit &amp; Loss`, Xerces is giving error:

```
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
<in-ab:TypeOfReport>Profit &amp; Loss</in-ab:TypeOfReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a CDATA which will then avoid to try to parse the ampersand

Comment: How to use CDATA?? Please help

Comment: [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) you enclose the string in <![CDATA[ foo & bar ]]>

Comment: IT IS NOT WORKING .. SHOWING ERROR AGAIN.

Comment: i HAVE DEPENDENCY ON THIS TAG.. if tag value is "Profit & amp ; Loss" then i have to some calculation

Comment: well you know caps lock is not very pleased to be seen arround the web this has a bad signification when you "talk" to someone else

Comment: Sorry.. i didn't saw that ... it will not be repeat next time :)